# How to get batch of array value from an array by incremental or decrements values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, It contains bunch of values in it. I would like to `slice` the array by increasing value of the `count` number or decreasing value of the `count`.

the count is updated by `next` and `prev` buttons. when user click on `next` the count increase and the user click on `prev` button the `count` decrease. using this wan to `slice` array values by my batch numbers.

here is my try:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var batch = 2;
var num = 2;
var total = arr.length;
var group = arr.slice(0, (batch % total));


var add = function (amount) {
     num = (num + total - 1 + amount) % total + (2)
     console.log(arr.slice((num-batch), (num % total)))
}

$('a').click(function (e) {
    var num = e.target.className == 'prev' ? -1 : 1;
    add(num);
})

console.log(group)
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7jbw234n/1/)

Comment: not working is not a good problem description. Please explain the problem with the actual output and expected output.

Comment: when i increment say, click on next i am getting next batch of slices from the array. when click prev button i am not getting previous batch of slices, please see the console for output.

Comment: I want get the `slice` by each 2 by increment or decrement of the buttons.

Comment: What should happen around the edges, for example after 8, when I press `Next`?

Comment: see the result, it's like circular output. you will get again from the start. in my try, again the array is not properly starting from start index. sorry for that - if you have any good solution let me know.

Comment: I am sorry, Stackoverflow doesn't work that way. The readers will not have to go through the demo to understand the problem. It should be clearly stated in the question itself.

Comment: Ok, let me update in to my question it self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're always looking for groupings of size `batch`, and want to wrap around your array, you could do something like this.

```
var add = function (amount) {
    num = ((num + batch * amount) % total + total) % total;

    var out = arr.slice(num, num + batch);
    if (out.length < batch) {
        out = out.concat( arr.slice(0, batch - out.length ) );
    }

    console.log(out);
}
```

Note that JavaScript `%` is not a modulo operator like in most languages, it is instead a remainder operator. Instead of putting you into the range [0, m - 1] it goes to the range [-m + 1, m - 1] while preserving sign (ie `-6 % 5 = -1`). An easy way to implement a true modulo is by doing doing `((n % m) + m) % m`.

Comment: Technically speaking, `%` is not a modulo operator, it is a [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder). There has been [talk of adding a true modulo operator](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:modulo_operator) to JavaScript in the future though.

Comment: Ah, true enough. Edited answer to reflect that.